# How to translate a json file as an error message with a working hyperlink

Tags: php, json, laravel, hyperlink

I have created a pop-up error message that will take in json response message. However I have translated the error to return a custom message including an email that I'm hoping to turn into a hyperlink that can be clicked and redirect the user. So far the message is able to be printed out as a json string and I'm not sure from here on how I can do to make that string into a hyperlink.

I have placed this line of code in `validation.php`

```
'attributes' => [
 'smtp.error' => 'Oops! Something went wrong with our mail. Drop us an email at <a href="mailto:'.config('settings.support_email').'">'.config('settings.support_email').'</a> instead.'
```

that is suppose to convert my string from my `en.json` file

```
"smtp.error" : "Oops! Something went wrong with our mail. Drop us an email at enquiry@helpme.com instead."
```

where smtp.error will translate the following error json response in my controller.

```
catch (Exception $e) {
 /*If there is an exception, get the json message and translate to what is declared as smtp.error*/
 return $request->ajax() ? response()->json(["message" => __('smtp.error')], 500) : back()->withInput()->with('error', $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing it like this `validation.php`

```
'attributes' => [
    'smtp.error' => trans('smtp.error', ['email' => config('settings.support_email')),
```

In `en.php`

```
"smtp.error" : 'Oops! Something went wrong with our mail. Drop us an email at <a href="mailto::email">:email</a> instead.'
```

Comment: How would the trans() function determine that the mail should be encapsulated in the <a href> tag?

Comment: @Monomoni sorry, didn't pay attention to the config variable. I've edited my answer

Comment: But I'm using the en.json so when it prints the errror message out as such, it would display the whole <a href> tag just as a string

Comment: if you are using blade, do it like this to not break the html tags `{!! trans('smtp.error', ['email' => $email]) !!}`